# Codeception with Selenium in docker container not able to see site to test it

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, codeception

I have my site running on a LEMP stack using docker-compose, all works great.

I've followed the official documentation for Selenium docker my composer file is an extract copy of theirs:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.12.0-cobalt
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.12.0-cobalt
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Then I've configured codeception exactly per documentation:

`acceptance.suite.yml`

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://172.22.1.2
            browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptence
```

`TestCest.php`

```
...
public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/');
    $I->see('Homepage');
}
...
```

When running the tests they timeout and fail saying `This site can't be reached`. The docker container is definitely running and is reachable via a web browser via the containers IP 172.22.1.2

The test all run and work when I use the default PhpBrowser so it seems codeception can't access the selenium docker container. Any advice on this?

EDIT.........
Adding docker-compose for clarity

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.1
      container_name: reports-mariadb
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=reports
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=reports
        - MYSQL_USER=reports
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=reports
      ports:
        - "8011:3306"
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.3

    webserver:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: reports-nginx
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8010:80"
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.2

    php-fpm:
      build: dev/php-fpm
      container_name: reports-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./dev/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.4

networks:
  reports:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.1.0/24
```

Answer (score 2):

After posting the question it came to me.... it's looking on localhost by default but because the Application is running inside of a virtual network 172.22.1.0/24 it's obviously a different localhost compared to that of the application containers.

So I moved the containers over to my main docker-compose file and added the `selenium-hub` to the virtual network like so:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.1
      container_name: reports-mariadb
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=reports
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=reports
        - MYSQL_USER=reports
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=reports
      ports:
        - "8011:3306"
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.3

    webserver:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: reports-nginx
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./dev/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8010:80"
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.2

    php-fpm:
      build: dev/php-fpm
      container_name: reports-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./dev/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
      networks:
        reports:
          ipv4_address: 172.22.1.4

    selenium-hub:
        image: selenium/hub:3.12.0-cobalt
        container_name: selenium-hub
        ports:
          - "4444:4444"
    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        environment:
          - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
          - HUB_PORT=4444
    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox:3.12.0-cobalt
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        environment:
          - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
          - HUB_PORT=4444

networks:
  reports:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.1.0/24
```

Then you just need to tell codeception what host it's running on:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://172.22.1.2
            host: 172.22.1.5
            browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptence
```